jquery-3.7.1.js:3784 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_fnCallbackReg')
I have a website biuld that uses jquery, Bootstrap and dataTables. The issue I have is the code generates an error:
jquery-3.7.1.js:3784 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_fnCallbackReg') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_fnCallbackReg')
I just need to check I am loading the scripts and plugins in the correct order. Any comments?
Script Order
<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-2.1.2/datatables.min.js"></script>


<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/dataTables.fixedColumns.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/fixedColumns.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/bootstrap-validate.js"></script>

<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/jquery-confirm.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/sorttable.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/jquery.form_navex_fids.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/jquery.smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../globalscripts/jquery.alphanum.js"></script>

